# Is "Underground" a proper noun or a common noun?

Tags: nouns, british-english, proper-nouns

The definition on the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/underground) is a little bit confusing for me. The dictionary doesn't call it a *proper noun*, but the first letter is capitalised in the example.

Since I know the Underground as a transportation system specific to a place (e.g. London), I would expect it to be a proper noun. Checking the dictionary didn't help me.

> **underground**
>
> NOUN
>
> 1. (often the Underground) *British* An underground railway, especially the one in London.
>
> ‘travel chaos on the Underground’

Is it a proper noun or a common noun?

Comment: Using the definite article, and thus defining the usage, makes the common noun proper. Thus 'the Underground' in London, the 'Subway' in Glasgow or the 'Metro' in Washington DC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition does not say that the word "underground" is specific to London.

"The Underground" in London is a proper noun (that's why it's capitalized).
"The Metro" in Paris is a proper noun (again, that's why it's capitalized).

If you're talking about underground train systems in general, what word do you use in England? You can't use ["subway"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/subway) because it means something different. So you use ["underground"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/underground) or ["metro"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/metro) — they're both common nouns in this usage.

If you ask whether anybody actually uses "underground" for anything other than the system in London, it seems to be incredibly rare. But the dictionary definition clearly suggests that this is one possible usage, and it would be this usage that is a common noun rather than a proper noun.

Comment: @Peter Shor, there is only one Underground in Britain - it is in London. There is a Subway in Glasgow. These are underground railway systems or classic "metros". There is a Metro in Tyne and Wear, which is a light rail system.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: The common noun would usually be used when talking about underground train systems in general, not when talking about one in a specific city. For example, from Google books: *"(AST) has gained broad experience in the design and implementation of undergrounds in major Italian and European cities; these works often interact with sites and structures belonging to the historic and artistic heritage."*

Comment: Did you notice my capitalisation?

Comment: Emilio Bilotta, ‎Alessandro Flora, ‎Stefania Lirer are not English names; I suspect they are Italian. The use of 'underground' as a generic term is unusual in Britain.

Comment: [Link here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+design+and+implementation+of+undergrounds%22&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS737US737&oq=%22the+design+and+implementation+of+undergrounds%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.1450j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).   I suspect most native English speakers in the U.K. would use "metro" for this meaning today, but the dictionary is also supposed to cover English as it was used earlier this century.

Comment: For example, [The Story of Tunnels](https://books.google.com/books?id=o1ZVAAAAMAAJ&q=%22undergrounds%22&dq=%22undergrounds%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-r6CVyuLcAhUR7lMKHfemAAIQ6AEIOzAE) by Archibald Black (1937), published in New York,  contains the quote *hence they had nothing in common with the modern undergrounds and subway systems of London and other cities.*

Comment: Archibald Black was an American. In Britain, (on the other side of the Atlantic), we rarely, if ever,  speak of 'undergrounds' when we mean 'underground railways'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81457/discussion-between-peter-shor-and-michael-harvey).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's relevant to why you need to know this, but in London they far more frequently call that underground railway "The Tube," which is a proper noun and should be capitalized. If you were to say, "The Underground," this would also be a proper noun and should be capitalized, although this phrase is not as locally common and is more formal, perhaps more posh or pretentious.

If you are using "metro," "underground," or "subway" in general terms, and are not specifying a particular system in a particular city, these words are not capitalized.